# Динамическая форма и sql запрос в потоке

Tags: delphi, многопоточность

Из основной формы создаю динамически дочернюю форму:

```
var
  SomeForm: TForm;
  FormClass: TFormClass;
begin
  try
    FormClass := TFormClass(FindClass('Tnof12Form'));
    SomeForm := FormClass.Create(Application);
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      MessageDlg('Не удалось открыть "nof12Form".' + #13#10 +
        'Error: Could not find class.', mtError, [mbOK], 0)
    end;
  end;
```

Форма создается и показывается. Далее мне необходимо из созданной дочерней формы запустить поток в котором будет выполнен запрос к бд и результат возвращен в ту же форму в компонент DBGrid.

```
unit no12;
interface
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Data.DB, Data.Win.ADODB, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Grids, Vcl.DBGrids;

type
  Tnof12Form = class(TForm)
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    Button1: TButton;
    Query: TADOQuery;
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  end;

  TPotok = class(TThread)
  private
    procedure DataSource;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

var
  nof12Form: Tnof12Form;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TPotok.DataSource;
begin
  nof12Form.DataSource1.DataSet := nof12Form.Query;
end;

procedure TPotok.Execute;
begin
  nof12Form.Query.Open;
  Synchronize(DataSource);
end;

procedure Tnof12Form.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Query.ConnectionString :='********';
  Query.sql.text := '***********';

  with TPotok.Create(True) do
  begin
    FreeOnTerminate := True;
    Resume;
  end;
end;

procedure Tnof12Form.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := caFree;
end;

Initialization
  RegisterClasses([Tnof12Form]);
end.
```

Вроде бы все хорошо, но на самом деле ничего хорошего.
При обычном запуске никаких ошибок, просто DBGrid ничего не отображает.
А вот при детальном рассмотрении выдает ошибку на `nof12Form.Query.Open;`:

> Project Forms.exe raised exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x008473ec: read of address 0x000003cc'.

Но, если я создаю дочернюю форму вот таким способом:

```
nof12Form := Tnof12Form.Create(Application);
```

или

```
Application.CreateForm(Tnof12Form, nof12Form);
```

То все отлично работает и DBGrid отображает результат запроса.

Никак не могу понять что делать.

Comment: $C0000005  обычно - вызов метода неинициализированного класса. Может, стоит вызывать не FormClass.Create, а FormClass.CreateNew?

Comment: Но в главной форме класс добавлен в initialization  RegisterClasses([Tnof12Form]);

Comment: а не может быть так, что переменная "var  SomeForm: TForm;" уничтожается после выхода из процедуры? Да и  "with TPotok.Create(True) do" по мне непривычно выглядит.

Comment: Проблема в том, что в потоке вы обращаетесь к конкретной переменной - `nof12Form`. А динамически созданная форма в эту переменную не попадает. Ну и внутри execute не стоит обращаться к `nof12Form.Query`

Comment: Мне не удаётся найти решение. Через дебагер я вижу что в переменную она е попадает, но как тогда решить вопрос?

Comment: В потоке заведите переменную типа `Tnof12Form`. При инициализации потока, в обработчике `OnClick` кнопки - заносите в эту переменную `Self`. Не `nof12Form`, а именно `Self`. И во внутренностях потока обращайтесь именно к этой заведенной переменной. А не к `nof12Form`. Ах, да... уйдите от with. Вообще забудьте про это слово.

Comment: Прошу прощения за свой тупизм, но никак не получается включить свою голову в правильном потоке.) Разжуйте пожалста что написали выше)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас есть глобальная переменная:

```
var
  nof12Form: Tnof12Form;
```

Когда вы создаете форму таким образом:

```
nof12Form := Tnof12Form.Create(Application);
```

то вы присваиваете этой переменной ссылку на экземпляр формы.
Когда вы создаете вот так:

```
Application.CreateForm(Tnof12Form, nof12Form);
```

То метод CreateForm создает экземпляр `Tnof12Form` и присваивает его в переменную `nof12Form` (так как второй параметр является выходным).
И всё работает. Но если вы создаете вот так:

```
var
  SomeForm: TForm;
  FormClass: TFormClass;
begin
  try
    FormClass := TFormClass(FindClass('Tnof12Form'));
    SomeForm := FormClass.Create(Application);
...
```

То созданный экземпляр формы попадает только в локальную переменную `SomeForm`, а глобальная переменная `nof12Form` остается неинициализированной. Поэтому впоследствии при обращении к ней:

```
nof12Form.Query.Open;
```

возникает ошибка доступа.

При создании потока вам нужно в него передать ссылку на экземпляр вашей формы, типа того:

```
with TPotok.Create(Self) do
  begin
    FreeOnTerminate := True;
    Resume;
  end;
```

Переписав при этом конструктор потока, конечно:

```
TPotok = class(TThread)
  private
    procedure DataSource;
  protected
    FForm: Tnof12Form; // <-- НОВАЯ ПЕРЕМЕННАЯ ДЛЯ ХРАНЕНИЯ ФОРМЫ
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AForm: Tnof12Form); reintroduce; // <-- НОВЫЙ КОНСТРУКТОР
  end;
...
implementation
...
procedure TPotok.Create(AForm: Tnof12Form);
begin
  FForm := AForm;
  inherited Create(True);
end;
```

и в потоке обращаться к нему, а не к глобальной переменной:

```
procedure TPotok.DataSource;
begin
  FForm.DataSource1.DataSet := nof12Form.Query;
end;

procedure TPotok.Execute;
begin
  FForm.Query.Open;
  Synchronize(DataSource);
end;
```

При таком подходе переменная:

```
var
  nof12Form: Tnof12Form;
```

вам вообще не нужна (хотя она может быть нужна, если `nof12Form` создается автоматически при старте проекта).

Comment: Большое спасибо, за развернутый ответ!